OpenRewrite - How to replace a method in a chained/fluent method invocation?
I am currently getting started with writing rewrite recipes and am struggling a bit with replacing methods in a fluent interface. In particular, I'd like to replace .isEqualTo(200) (and once that works also .isEqualTo(HttpStatusCode.valueOf(200)) with .isOk():
Before:
import org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClient;

class Test {
    private final WebTestClient webClient = WebTestClient.bindToServer().build();
    void someMethod() {
      webClient
          .post()
          .uri("/some/endpoint")
          .bodyValue("someValue")
          .exchange()
          .expectStatus()
          .isEqualTo(200);
    }
}

After:
import org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClient;

class Test {
    private final WebTestClient webClient = WebTestClient.bindToServer().build();
    void someMethod() {
      webClient
          .post()
          .uri("/some/endpoint")
          .bodyValue("someValue")
          .exchange()
          .expectStatus()
          .isOk();
    }
}

I have come up with the following visitor that is matching the isEqualTo method and replacing it with isOk():
@Override
public JavaIsoVisitor<ExecutionContext> getVisitor() {
    return new JavaIsoVisitor<ExecutionContext>() {

        private final MethodMatcher methodMatcher
            = new MethodMatcher("org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.StatusAssertions isEqualTo(..)");
        private final JavaType JAVA_TYPE_INT = JavaType.buildType("int");
        private final JavaTemplate isOkTemplate 
            = JavaTemplate.builder("isOk()").build();

        @Override
        public MethodInvocation visitMethodInvocation(MethodInvocation method, ExecutionContext p) {
            // exit if method doesn't match isEqualTo(..)
            if (!methodMatcher.matches(method.getMethodType())) {
                return method;
            }
            Expression expression = method.getArguments().get(0);
            // isEqualTo has two signatures: isEqualTo(int) and isEqualTo(HttpStatusCode)
            // handle `isEqualTo(int) here
            if(expression instanceof Literal) {
                if(JAVA_TYPE_INT.equals(expression.getType())) {
                    Literal literal = (Literal) expression;
                    if(literal.getValue() instanceof Integer) {
                        if ((int) literal.getValue() == 200) {
                            MethodInvocation m = isOkTemplate.apply(getCursor(), method.getCoordinates().replace());
                            return m;
                        }
                    }
                    return method;
                }
                return method;
            }
            return super.visitMethodInvocation(method, p);
        }
    };
}

This implementation is replacing the whole webClient invocation (webClient.post().(..).isOk()) with isOk():
import org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClient;
  
class Test {
    private final WebTestClient webClient = WebTestClient.bindToServer().build();
    void someMethod() {
        isOk();
    }
}

Having the MethodInvocation nesting in mind that is described in the LST examples document, I would guess that my MethodMatcher is too specific and I would actually need to capture the outmost invocation and somehow stream() over it and replace the nested isEqualTo invocation.
Can someone point me in the right direction?

Could make for a nice contribution to https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite-spring/ if you're up for it; that also saves you from having to maintain this going forward. :)

I'll think about it :)

I'd say you're really close; What you're currently doing is replacing the whole method, and with that the select that it's called upon. Did you already try replaceMethod instead of replace for the coordinates?

Alternatively you do something like return m.withSelect(method.getSelect()) to retain the chain before.

Thanks for the quick reply! That indeed did the trick.

Some unrelated feedback: I really like the openrewrite documentation and the starter tutorials!
One gotcha that I got though was that the beginner tutorials like Writing a Java refactoring recipe, Getting started with Refaster template recipes or Modifying methods with JavaTemplate all work without dependencies.

I know there is Using multiple versions of a library in a project that deals with this implicitly, but I feel like there is something missing in the learning curve.
Maybe one of the other articles could be changed to modify code of some library to get familiar with the aspect of adding dependencies to the pom/build.gradle and explicitly loading that in a test case.

Thanks for calling that out! Some explicit beginner material on dependencies would be a good addition to the docs indeed, as I've also been surprised previously that pages like the one on JavaTemplate does not list any classpath dependencies. There's a balance of course in having simple examples and building up that complexity, but this is a gap to be filled.

And glad to hear we got you going! Feel free to also join our Slack if you have more quick questions. I'll monitor here all the same, but it's a bit more async.
